# What is IDFA? do I need to tick it when submitting apps when I am using iAD?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I don't seem to use the ASIdentifierManager class but my app serves iAds...

should i tick the check box

"Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?"

on submission of my app? thanks

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, however, I suspect that it's about a setting in iTunesConnect and is probably off topic.

Comment: well thank you for voting down. I just hate you so much

Comment: From articles I've read, if you're using iAd exclusively you do not need to tick yes. If you're using AdMob or any other ad network that uses the AdSupport.framework then you will need to tick yes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Upvoted your comment and also the question.